# what is the best (and free) tool to disable/enable USB ports

Tags: windows-7, usb, security, usb-storage

I want to disable USB ports (for everything except mouse and mobile phone) on my family computer. It runs on the Windows 7 home basic.

The idea is that the guests should not be able to plug in their pen drives or storage devices. However, my wife and kid should be able to connect their mobile phone (and mouse, of course).

I am looking for a best but free software tool for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device manager. Just disable whatever you want disabled. Guest accounts cannot change those settings.

Comment: How can I select what to disable in Device Manager. It allows me to disable a port so I can disable all of them. But then mouse and phone will also not work. Right?

Comment: True. However, you can disable it for one user and not another (would be easy if you had anything other than home or starter version of 7, but should be possible in all versions).